# Bootstrap 3 Off Canvas not showing full height on small pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the Bootstrap 3 Off Canvas menu and it works fine except where the main page has very little content.  My menu is about 400 px long, and if the body of my document is say, 200px, I only see half the menu.

I tried giving the menu a height, but it had no effect.

Any ideas?

I see other questions where users have problems with the menu slipping under the header, but this is a different problem.

Comment: Are you using https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/offcanvas/ ?

Comment: If you are using the above template. Try applying a CSS min height equal to the height of your side menu to the .row-offcanvas element. ie min-height:400px.

Comment: add code snippet.

Comment: Yes Praveen, that is what I am using.

Comment: Hey Praveen, nice work.  That sorted it out.  Why don't you make it an answer for me to accept?

Comment: @PraveenMurali It worked according to OP, post an answer and get your reward! P.S. To grab someone's attention, Kim, you have to use @ and their name to address them (unless it's a comment in their own answer/question).